# why tags get appended with time - jquery

Tags: jquery

In html I am giving `id(technology)` for input field.
I have added code like:

```
   $('#technology').tagsInput({ .... });
```

jquery runs and the result is

```
      <input id="tags1462968029982_tag" class="input_tag" />
```

The `id` changes from `"technology"` to `"tags1462968029982_tag"`

Validation are not working in the above scenario.

here is the code:

```
    $('#technology').importTags("");
    $('#technology').importTags("<?php echo !empty($skills)?$skills:''; ?>");
    $('#technology').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        'defaultText': '',
        autocomplete_url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url('/job_postings/get_technical_skills'); ?>",
        autocomplete: {
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url('/job_postings/get_technical_skills/'); ?>" + request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.ConfigTechnology.technology,
                                value: item.ConfigTechnology.technology,
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        onAddTag: function () {
            if ($('#technology').val() && x != 'test') {
                $("#technology_tagsinput").removeClass('error');
                $("label[for=technology]").hide();
            }
        },
        onRemoveTag: function () {
            if ($('#technology').val() && x != 'test') {
                $("#technology_tagsinput").removeClass('error');
                $("label[for=technology]").hide();
            }
            else if (x != 'test') {
                $("#technology_tagsinput").addClass('error');
                $("label[for=technology]").show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how did you assign the id?

Comment: I written in cakephp like this :

                                <?php echo $this->Form->text('technology', array('id' => 'technology', 'class' => 'form_input_small', 'div' => false, 'label' => false)); ?>

Comment: I am trying to use this plugin with jquery. when changing the view, id on the input seems to be append with time like "tags1462968029982_tag". Is there a reason for this and how can I avoid it??

Comment: what is the `tagsInput` plugin? - looks like whatever it does, it changes the id

Comment: share entire code plz

Comment: formatted the text and corrected the grammer part